# How to avoid word continue next line

Tags: line-breaks

When the browser size is small. The word will continue at next line.
(word "Dividen"
[image]

If the browser is wide enough. It will display well.
[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I am not sure it cause by css or programming.@user3437460

Comment: You have to be specific especially on tagging, so you will get the revelant help. Or at least describe your problem as detail as possible.

Comment: I changed the theme to another the problem solve. It that css problem? If it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: You should add that to your question and add css to the tag or other tags that is related to what you are doing. Since you are developing the project you should know the details and the problem, but all those isn't stated in your post. Anyway it wasn't me who down voted this post.

Answer (score 0):

For that we have perfect CSS property called "word-break".
You should set

`.my-class {word-break: keep-all;}`